# Command prompt shows C:\Users\user> by defaut

Tags: command-prompt

I tried to run my `.java` file by using command prompt but it wont find my file. I believe that the problem is that the line that shows as soon as I open Command Prompt is:   `C:\Users\user>`

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: How did you try to run your file ? Where is the command ? Is the Java file also in C:\Users\user ? Do you know what "C:\Users\user" means ?

Comment: i am not sure what it means and my java file is ine my desktop

Comment: I would strongly recommend you go through some basic windows training, and some java for beginners training online . . With Videos. And also try to use an IDE instead of directly "opening .java file with command prompt", this is not how you go about it.

Comment: thanks for the tip :)